# JavaScript map library with individual map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps

I would like to create my own map, based on the GoogleMaps functions. But not with the  real world map. The map I want to create is a fantasy map. For example I want to make a map of „Middle Earth“ (Lord of the Ring) - not really but some kind like that :-) 
I have already found some free libraries but this are always based on the real map of the earth.

It would be ok if it has only the simplest functions, like scrolling (zooming), add some pins or stuff like that. 
No routing stuff needed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a mapping tool like http://leafletjs.com/ and load in custom tiles.

This guy used it I think to create an interactive map of Guild Wars 2 https://github.com/lpdumas/gw2cartographers I had a brief look at it a while ago, quite a lot of code

Answer (score 0):

Another option for the mapping functionality would be [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/), in practice it is fairly similar in usage to the Google Maps API if you have any experience with this. It's open source and easy to use.

You will however have to provide your own custom map tiles.